# Directly setting accessToken to Mapbox throws Imports are immutable error

Tags: reactjs, angular, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl

When accessToken is directly set to mapboxgl, it throws an error.

> Imports are immutable in Javascript. To modify the value of this import, you must export a setter function in the imported file (e.g "setAccessToken") and then import and call that function here instead.

```
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid different kind of errors like

1. **Imports are Immutable error** during the compilation phase when directly setting this as

   `mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR_TOKEN';`
2. **set is not a function error** on the browser when you have hosted your compiled artifact with the static method

   `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(mapboxgl, "accessToken"). set(YOUR_TOKEN');`

You nee to directly set this on the `ACCESS_TOKEN` property present on `mapboxgl.config`

```
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

mapboxgl.config.ACCESS_TOKEN = 'YOUR_TOKEN';
```